# Parsing OkHttp in android?

Tags: java, android

```
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textVieww);
    String url = "https://zenquotes.io/api/random";
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(myResponse);
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Quote.this.runOnUiThread(() ->
                        textView.setText(myResponse));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the part im stuck on i think im on the right track but not sure where to go from here im trying to get the "q" information from the returned url and the "a" information but it just outputs everything any suggestions?

Comment: thanks for the help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

#### What was your problem

Even when you parsed JSON string, you were still using the myResponse string in your textView.setText() method.

#### Continuing your code snippet

your code snippet is quite short, but i do think i can quite understand what you mean.

So let's say that we have Activity, which is called MainActivity and in that activity we have two views, one TextView called that has an id of tv_author_and_quote and one Button which has a xml id btn_request_quote.
The button has an OnClickListener which calls method requestForQuote().

Our onCreate + the variables of Button and TextView  looks like this:

```
TextView tvAuthorAndQuote;
Button btnRequestQuote;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvAuthorAndQuote = findViewById(R.id.tv_author_and_quote);
    btnRequestQuote = findViewById(R.id.btn_request_quote);

    btnRequestQuote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            requestForQuote();
        }
    });
}
```

And then we have a code itself for method requestForQuote():

```
    public void requestForQuote() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
                    String myFormattedQuote = "";
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(myResponse);
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String quote = obj.getString("q");
                            String author = obj.getString("a");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: quote:" + quote);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: author:" + author);
                            myFormattedQuote = author + ": " + quote;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    final String myFinalQuote = myFormattedQuote;
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                if (!myFinalQuote.equals("")) {
                                    tvAuthorAndQuote.setText(myFinalQuote);
                                } else {
                                    tvAuthorAndQuote.setText(myResponse);
                                }
                            });

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The code above basically uses your existing solution, but instead of setting the text of textView with myResponse string, it parses the json array and gets a quote and an author from it. Then it just logs it (just for testing purposes), then it constructs the string which gets displayed to the if there is any, otherwise it prints the response. That it is.

#### Using Gson library

import it into your gradle dependecies

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
```

Write short "holder" class called **Quote**

```
public class Quote {

    public Quote() {
    }

    String q;
    String a;
    String h;

    public String getQ() {
        return q;
    }

    public void setQ(String q) {
        this.q = q;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(String h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a + ": " + q;
    }
}
```

Then the requestForQuote() method could look something like this:

```
public void requestForQuoteWithGson() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();

                    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Quote>>(){}.getType();
                    List<Quote> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(myResponse, listType);

                    if (yourClassList != null && yourClassList.size() > 0) {
                        final Quote quote = yourClassList.get(0);
                        if (quote != null) {
                            myQuotes.add(quote);
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() ->
                                    tvAuthorAndQuote.setText(quote.toString())
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```